# How to replace value within a bracket in python

Tags: python, regex, string, python-re

Given `string = "a(a123-bcd-a456)ppll"`

Goal: replace the `"a"` that are **within** the bracket with `"A"`

Desire output = `"a(A123-bcd-A456)ppll"`

I have tried:

```
regex = '\(.*?\)'
re.sub(regex, string, string.replace("a", "A"))
```

but it results in `Aa(a123-bcd-a456)ppllppll`?

Comment: `string.replace("a", "A")` is called *before* the regex function is called, and produces the string `"A(A123-bcd-A456)ppll"`. Then the `re.sub` uses *that* to replace the bracket contents that it finds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `re.sub` with a callback function:

```py
string = "a(a123-bcd-a456)ppll"
output = re.sub(r'\((.*?)\)', lambda x: '(' + x.group(1).replace('a', 'A') + ')', string)
print(output)  # a(A123-bcd-A456)ppll
```

The strategy here is first to capture the content inside the parentheses `(...)`, which is then passed to a lambda callback function.  Inside the lambda we replace `a` with `A`.